# How to set yum to use tor on CentOs 7?

Tags: linux, networking, centos7

I have centos 7 and i want to set yum to use tor as proxy server. I installed tor and as you know tor is installed on 127.0.0.1 and port 9050. How can i force yum to download http and https and ftp through tor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit /etc/yum.conf and added:

```
  proxy=socks5h://localhost:9050
```